# Confusing part of Grobner Basis section of Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, I was reading section 9.6 in Dummit and Foote, and I got a bit confused by the proof below, particularly the part where they claim $f_{i-1}'-f_i'=S(f_{i-1}, f_i)$. This is on page 323.

[image: Dummit_Foote]

For example, let $f_1=x^3y$ and let $f_2=x^2y^2$. Then $S(f_1, f_2)=yf_1-xf_2=0$. However, $f_1'=f_1$, and $f_2'=f_2$, since both polynomials are already monic, but $f_1'-f_2'=f_1-f_2\neq 0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't have Dummit and Foote near me, but I am fairly sure that your two polynomials don't have the same multidegree. (Also, please cite your texts in such a way that the post still makes sense when the externally hosted images expire -- so, say something to the extent of "Lemma 25 in section 9.6 of Dummit and Foote, $x$-th edition" (fill in the $x$ please). Thank you.)

Comment: Ah, that's it. I thought multidegree meant the sum of the degrees of the each variables, when it actually means the ordered tuple of degrees of each variable. Thanks!

Comment: What you meant is called total degree.